# Where to get PostScript printer driver for HP OfficeJet Pro 8210?

Tags: drivers, printer, postscript, tails-os, hp

The Tails-developers have inserted a pretty nice PostScript printer driver for HP OfficeJet Pro 8210 into Tails.

I am strongly searching on where to get this driver, so I already installed the packages...

- `hplip`
- `hplip-data`
- `hpijs-ppds`
- `printer-driver-hpijs`
- `printer-driver-hpcups`
- `printer-driver-postscript-hp`

... but none of them provided this driver they have integrated in Tails.

---

Tails is based on Debian 9 (Stretch) what I am using as well, so where can I get this driver? I guess the Tails-developers did not insert the driver into their system manually by hand? Probably they took it from any common driver package as well.

All I know is that this driver is listed in the *Tails Printer Driver Database*, but where to get it?

Comment: Tails is Debian based distribution, so you can find it in a Debian package.

Comment: @IporSircer: That's completely right! But which package is it? :-)

Comment: `dpkg -S /path/to/driver` will show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the additional package `foomatic-db` beside of `printer-driver-postscript-hp` brought the solution.

The printer is working completely fine with this!